# No response from POST to custom REST Api route

Tags: magento-1.9, api, rest-api, json, post-data

**I set up a working custom route for Magento's REST Api.**

It works fine for GET requests, as the `_retrieve()` function of the corresponding `V1.php` class is being called as expected and returns the data. But now I'm trying to handle POST requests and that's when Magento is behaving weird:

- When you want to post data you have to define the data as a collection instead of an entity in `etc/api2.xml` like this: `<action_type>collection</action_type>`. Otherwise Magento will throw this error in `Mage_Api2_Model_Resource` (line 207):

```
// Creation of objects is possible only when working with collection
$this->_critical(self::RESOURCE_METHOD_NOT_IMPLEMENTED);
```

So when I define the action_type as collection, then the `_multiCreate()` function of the corresponding `V1.php` is being called as expected.

- However Magento now doesn't let me return any data. I want to return this array in JSON format:

  `$response = array("success"=>true, "error"=>"", "model"=>array(1,2,3));`

'success', 'error' and 'model' are defined as attributes in the api2.xml and should therefore be available. But when I return `$response`, the response is empty with 
Status 207 ... Hmmm! Now since it has action_type collection, I have also tried to return the `$response` wrapped inside another array, but without success.

In my final tryouts I figured out that by setting data with the method `$this->getResponse()->addMessage(....)` I am able to retrieve data, but I don't think that this is the correct way as it is thought to be for success/error/warning message types and it doesn't fit my data type requirements.

Last but not least I also tried to return data by using the `$this->getResponse()->setBody($result)` and `$this->getResponse()->setRawBody($result)` methods, but again - no success:

**So Magento experts - What is the correct way to retrieve data from a POST request to the REST Api? I desperately need your help!!**

Here's my `api2.xml`:

```
<customer_login translate="title" module="Test_Restapi">
    <group>restapi</group>
    <model>restapi/api2_customer_login</model>
    <title>Blablabla</title>
    <sort_order>10</sort_order>
    <privileges>
        <customer>
            <create>1</create>
            <update>1</update>
            <retrieve>1</retrieve>
        </customer>
        <guest>
            <create>1</create>
            <update>1</update>
            <retrieve>1</retrieve>
        </guest>
    </privileges>
    <attributes>
        <success>Success</success>
        <error>Error</error>
        <model>Model</model>
    </attributes>
    <routes>
        <route_collection>
            <route>/restapi/customer/login</route>
            <action_type>collection</action_type>
        </route_collection>
    </routes>
    <versions>1</versions>
</customer_login>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at class `Mage_Api2_Model_Resource` which should be extended by your class, you can find function `_render()`.

By examining `dispach()` function of this class, you can see, that `_render()` function is called by retrieve operations. So you can use this function at the end of your action like so `$this->_render($data)`.

This function is not used by create operations, which only set Location header to newly created resource url.

To take an advantage of attribute filtering, use `$this->getFilter()->out($data)` before `$this->_render($data)`

`Mage_Api2_Model_Resource::dispatch()` can answer a lot of questions regarding magento REST!

Comment: Thanks for your note. I will have a look at the `_render()` function and let you know if it worked ..

Answer (score 0):

I managed to retrieve data from the `_createMulti()` function by following @raivis.krumins suggestions. Inside the `dispatch()` function of the `Mage_Api2_Model_Resource` class I added these 3 lines after line 228 at the end of the `if` statement where the location header is being set:

```
$retrievedData = $this->_createMulti($filteredData);
$returnData  = $this->getFilter()->out($retrievedData);
$this->_render($returnData);
```

The first line retrieves the result from the function, the second line filters out unwanted attributes (the ones not set in `api2.xml`) and finally the third line returns the data in the response.

Please note that these changes should always be made in a custom module. Never change a core class!

Answer (score 0):

Just before reruns in your custom module function set

$this->getResponse()->appendBody(json_encode($response));